# Button template is masking the clickable area of a button

Tags: xaml, windows-10, uwp, vector-graphics

I have the following UWP XAML:

```
<Button Content="Scan" 
    Command="{Binding CommandScan}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Scan"
    Style="{StaticResource ButtonIconStyle}">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <resources:ScanIcon />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

`ScanIcon` is a user control that contains a vector image.  What seems to be happening is that the icon is masking the clickable button area - that is, I can click in the drawn area of the icon only, the background of the button (whilst still within the border of the button) is not clickable.

So, my questions are: What is causing this behaviour, and how can I override it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to leave `Button` `ControlTemplate` alone and insert your image into `Background` of `Button`. I mean - you don't have to shoot big guns when you simple want to override style. If you need the `Button` to be exactly the shape of the image you can try `DrawingBrush` as described here: [Painting with Images, Drawings, and Visuals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms749021(v=vs.100).aspx)